# X-windows middle-mouse button using touchpad on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, cygwin, touchpad, cygwin-x

Cygwin is the only unix environment of which I know that works on top of Windows.  I am getting frequent reminders to move from Windows 7 to Windows 10.  It doesn't make sense to migrate my 2011 laptop with stuck keys to Windows 10, so I've been investigating current day laptops.  I haven't bought one yet, but have messed around with display models at stores.

In Windows 10, one can specify that a [3-finger tap as representing the tap of the middle mouse button](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/26552/stupid-geek-tricks-use-both-laptop-mouse-buttons-to-simulate-middle-click).  Unfortunately, it is only a tap, and not a click-and-hold.  X-windows requires the emulation of all possible uses of the middle button: Tap, click-and-hold, either of those two in conjunction with Shift and/or Control, and either one of the preceding modes in conjuction with a drag.  For example, `xterm` customization menus require some of these.

In Windows 7, I achieve this by mapping the left physical button to the desired middle button.  I don't need the physical left button to behave as a left button because left button functionality can be emulated with touch pad taps and drags by enabling the following Synaptics's switches:

- Tap again and hold to drag
- Locking Drags

Other limitations:

- I avoid carrying extra accessories like a mouse because without a doubt, I will not have it when I need it
- Many laptops don't have explicit buttons, but allow lower left/right corners to be clicked.  This prevents the emulation of middle button by clicking both left and right, which isn't a good option anyway because (I'm guessing that) it also doesn't allow for simultaneous drag.

**Questions**

- How have other Cygwin users obtained middle mouse button functionality in Windows 10?
- Is Synaptics compatible with Windows 10
- Will it accomplish what I describe above with Windows 7?

Comment: A number of LogiTech mice provide click and hold built-in. Both my mice here (one on each computer) allow click and hold. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Actually, I am looking for solution that i know will always be available, and that rules out a mouse.  I'm seeking a solution using the touchpad.

Comment: You are out of date. Windows 10 supports an [integrated Linux environment](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

Comment: Wow.  Very cool.  Does it have as broad a set of packages as Cygwin? As a product of a single commercial entity, are users in a more vulnerable position in developing a reliance on it?  As well, does it have a solution for the middle mouse question?  Thanks for elaborating.

Comment: From my reading up on WSL so far, it seems that I need to install an X-server.  If I'm going to do that, e.g., via Cygwin, then I'm thinking that I might as well install everything via Cygwin.  But none of this really addresses the question of how the X-windows middle-mouse button is realized on a Windows 10 machine.